# jquery get elements attibute value and create variable from it

Tags: jquery

Can any one please help me solve this.

I am resizing some flash object/embed code to fit the browser window using jquery. Please see HTML below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="prezi">

     <object id="prezi_3453246342644353463435463456435" width="1000" height="800">

          <embed width="1000" height="800" ></embed>

     </object>

</div>
```

**JQUERY (THIS WORKS)**

```
function preziresize() {

    var $objectId =       $('#prezi_3453246342644353463435463456435'),
        $objectEmbed =    $objectId.find('embed'),
        windowWidth =     $(window).width(),
        windowHeight =    $(window).height();

        $objectId.attr( 'height' , windowHeight ).attr( 'width' , windowWidth );

        $objectEmbed.attr( 'height' , windowHeight ).attr( 'width' , windowWidth ); 

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    preziresize();

});

$(window).resize(function() {

    preziresize();

});
```

**MY PROBLEM**

But the downfall of the script above, is that I have to manually put the ID of my object into my script. :(

On my new script, which is not working, I am trying to automatically get the id of the object, and assign it as a variable. Please see my function below.

```
function preziresize() {

    var $objectId =     $('#prezi').attr( 'id' ),
        $objectEmbed =  $objectId.find('embed'),
        windowWidth =   $(window).width(),
        windowHeight =  $(window).height();

        $objectId.attr( 'height' , windowHeight ).attr( 'width' , windowWidth );

        $objectEmbed.attr( 'height' , windowHeight ).attr( 'width' , windowWidth ); 

}
```

Any pointers would be great thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** You should better execute it on resize too.

```
$(window).bind("resize.preziresize", function() {
   $('div#prezi object')
       .find('embed')
       .andSelf()
       .attr( 'height' , $(window).height() )
       .attr( 'width' , $(window).width() );
}).trigger("resize.preziresize");
```

Comment: WOW - this is alot simpler, great way of thinking! Though how would I get this to work on document ready too? Only works on window resize. Thanks

Comment: Hmmmm, I added this code into my document, but only works on window resize. If I wrap your code in document ready then it works -

Answer (score 2):

```
var $object =     $('#prezi').find("object"),
    $objectEmbed =  $object.find('embed'),
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great, don't know why I didn't do this. :-)

Answer (score -1):

This code doesn't make much sense, sinse $("#prezi") means you already know it's id, it's "prezi". the other problem with your code is that $objectId is a string and not the jQuery object, so you can't use .find on it. Try this:

```
function preziresize() {    
    var $object =       $('#prezi object'),
        $objectId =     $object.attr('id')
        $objectEmbed =  $object.find('embed'),
        windowWidth =   $(window).width(),
        windowHeight =  $(window).height();

        $object.attr( 'height' , windowHeight ).attr( 'width' , windowWidth );
        $objectEmbed.attr( 'height' , windowHeight ).attr( 'width' , windowWidth ); 
}
```